# Base64 encoder in Assembly x86-64 Linux language

Tags: linux, assembly, base64, byte

We were asked to create a Base64 encoder for Assembly x86-64 on Linux. Was wondering how my code below could be improved, be it notation or anything else. We only had Assembly for 3 months so I'm not really that used to any kind of particular notation. That's a reason why I'm asking. Thanks for your help !

```
SECTION .data           
Base64Table: db "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"


SECTION .bss

byteStorage: resb 30000
bytesToReadAtOnce: equ 30000
    
    
b64EncStor: resb 40000
b64EncStorLen: equ $ - b64EncStor
    

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:

;sys read   put everything from the file into the buffer "byteStorage"
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, byteStorage
mov rdx, bytesToReadAtOnce
syscall


xor r11, r11 ; syscall strangely changes r11
xor r12, r12    ;r12 will keep track of index in byteStorage array
mov r13, 0  ;r13 will keep track of index in b64EncStor array


.encodingInProgress:

cmp rax, 0
je .weHaveFinished      ;if no bits remaining, and no extra one or two  
                        ;bytes, we simply jump to the end
dec rax
inc r12


mov r8b, [byteStorage + r12 -1]     ; put each input char in a register each

mov r11b, r8b
shr r11b, 2
and r11b, 0x3F

mov r11b, [Base64Table + r11]

mov [b64EncStor + r13], r11b    ; our first char is now encoded
inc r13

cmp rax, 0      ;if rax = 0, rax was one before above decrementation, so we jump
je .oneExtraByte    ;to .oneExtraByte

;char two

dec rax
inc r12

mov r9b, [byteStorage + r12-1]  ; put each input char in a register each

and r8b, 0x3
shl r8b,4
mov r11b, r9b
shr r11b, 4
and r11b, 0xF
add r8b, r11b

mov r8b, [Base64Table + r8]

mov [b64EncStor+r13], r8b   ; second char now encoded
inc r13

cmp rax, 0      ;rax was two before being decremented twice above, so we 
je .twoExtraBytes  ;jump to .twoExtraBytes

;char three

dec rax
inc r12

mov r10b, [byteStorage + r12-1] ;put each input char in a register each

and r9b, 0xF
shl r9b, 2
mov r8b, r10b
shr r8b, 6
and r8b, 0x3
add r9b, r8b

mov r9b, [Base64Table +  r9]

mov [b64EncStor+r13], r9b   ; third char now encoded
inc r13

;char four

and r10b, 0x3F

mov r10b, [Base64Table + r10]

mov [b64EncStor+r13], r10b  ; fourth char now encoded
inc r13

jmp .encodingInProgress

;--------

.oneExtraByte:  ;so we need four (and not two !) bits more to reach 12

shl r8b, 4
and r8b, 0x3F   ;only keep six bits from left, the two most right are zero

mov r8b, [Base64Table + r8]

mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
inc r13

mov r8b, "="        ;add two extra equal signs

mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
inc r13
mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
inc r13

jmp .weHaveFinished

;------

.twoExtraBytes: ;so we need two (and not four !) bits more to reach 18

;inc r12

mov r10b, [byteStorage + r12-1] ;put each input char in a register each

shl r10b, 2
and r10b, 0x3F  ;only keep six bits from left, the two most right are zero

mov r10b, [Base64Table + r10]

mov [b64EncStor + r13], r10b
inc r13

mov r8b, "="    ;add one extra equal sign

mov [b64EncStor  + r13], r8b
inc r13

jmp .weHaveFinished

;--------

.weHaveFinished:

;syscall for write, to output the result
mov rax, 1     
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, b64EncStor
mov rdx, r13
syscall


xor r12,r12

mov rax, 60         ; System call for exit
mov rdi, 0          
syscall
```

Comment: Feel free to comment if anything is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wiping registers

> ```
> mov rax, 0
> mov rdi, 0
> xor r11, r11
> xor r12, r12
> mov r13, 0
> ```

The preferred way to clear a register is to use the `xor reg, reg` instruction. It's  small and fast. From the above it would seem that you knew this already but didn't apply it consistently. But there's more to it than just using `xor`. It is best to only have `xor` operate on the low 32 bits because the CPU will zero the high 32 bits automatically. For the 'old' registers (`RAX`, `RBX`, ... ) this will shave off a REX prefix:

```
xor eax, eax
xor edi, edi
xor r11d, r11d
xor r12d, r12d
xor r13d, r13d
```

### A lurking danger

> ```
> mov r8b, [Base64Table + r8]
> mov r9b, [Base64Table +  r9]
> mov r10b, [Base64Table + r10]
> ```

Your program only ever writes to the lowest byte of the `r8`, `r9`, and `r10` registers. There's no guarantee whatsoever that the whole 64-bit register will be suitable for indexing like you plan. Best add the following to your wipe list:

```
xor r8d, r8d
xor r9d, r9d
xor r10d, r10d
```

### Redundant operations

> ```
> shr r11b, 2
> and r11b, 0x3F
> ```

The `shr` instruction already cleared the 2 topmost bits. There's no need for the `and` instruction that would do the same thing.

---

> ```
> and r8b, 0x3
> shl r8b,4
> mov r11b, r9b
> shr r11b, 4
> and r11b, 0xF
> add r8b, r11b
> ```

Here the same redundancy with shifting and anding `r11b`. In this case however you can consolidate both these `and`'s:

```
shl r8b, 4
mov r11b, r9b
shr r11b, 4
add r8b, r11b
and r8b, 0x3F
```

---

> ```
> and r9b, 0xF
> shl r9b, 2
> mov r8b, r10b
> shr r8b, 6
> and r8b, 0x3
> add r9b, r8b
> ```

And again the same redundancy with shifting and anding `r8b`. Consolidating both `and`'s gives:

```
shl r9b, 2
mov r8b, r10b
shr r8b, 6
add r9b, r8b
and r9b, 0x3F
```

---

> ```
> jmp .weHaveFinished
> ;--------
> .weHaveFinished:
> ```

The code can just as well fall through at this point. The `jmp` is redundant.

### Optimizations

> ```
> dec rax
> ...
> cmp rax, 0          ;if rax = 0, rax was one before above decrementation
> je  .oneExtraByte   ; we jump to .oneExtraByte
> ```

You can safely delay executing the `dec rax` instruction. The code at the ellipsis doesn't depend on the value that's in `RAX`. Instead of inspecting using `cmp`, inspect the flags from using `dec`. Apply this trick 3 times:

```
test rax, rax       ; `TEST RAX, RAX` is preferred over `CMP RAX, 0`
jz .weHaveFinished
.encodingInProgress:

...
dec rax
jz  .oneExtraByte

...
dec rax
jz  .twoExtraBytes

...
dec rax
jnz .encodingInProgress
jmp .weHaveFinished

;----------------------------------

.oneExtraByte:
```

---

> ```
> mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
> inc r13
>
> mov r8b, "="        ;add two extra equal signs
>
> mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
> inc r13
> mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
> inc r13
>
> jmp .weHaveFinished
> ```

All of this incrementing on `r13` is overkill. The code is about to end anyway. Just write it like:

```
mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
mov word [b64EncStor + r13 + 1], "=="
jmp .weHaveFinished
```

### Style

To improve readability, you could start all of your tail-comments at the same column. (same goes for instruction mnemonics and operands)
Also be consistent with how you use whitespace. eg. I see the following:

> ```
> mov [b64EncStor + r13], r11b    ; our first char is now encoded
> mov [b64EncStor+r13], r8b   ; second char now encoded
> mov [b64EncStor  + r13], r8b
> ```

Wouldn't you agree that

```
mov [b64EncStor + r13], r11b    ; our first char is now encoded
mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b     ; second char now encoded
mov [b64EncStor + r13], r8b
```

is nicer to look at?